# How to divide the country_map into more than just the country regions in Apache Superset?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-superset

I am using Apache Superset, specifically [country_map](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/_images/country_map.png) to visualize  data.

Is it possible to slice the country maps into more areas than just the [regions](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/visualization.html#list-of-countries) of the country? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make changes to country maps, you need to build Superset from sources.
First, fork the Apache Superset repo in your Github. Then clone the repo to your device and enter superset folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/incubator-superset.git
cd incubator-superset
```

Second:

```
sudo pip install -r docs/requirements.txt
python3 setup.py build_sphinx
```

Next, create virtual environment and install superset:

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv # if virtualenv not found use: `sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv`
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements-dev.txt # Here I got error "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1. You can skip it or try pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install -e .
fabmanager create-admin --app superset

pip install python-dotenv # just in case you don't already have it
superset db upgrade # if error pip install pandas==0.23.4 plus pip install sqlalchemy==1.2.18
superset load_examples 
superset init
```

Leave the `venv` environment to continue building the front-end:

```
deactivate # exit venv
cd superset/assets
npm ci
npm run dev
```

Next, go back to superset directory and start the flask local server:

```
cd superset
FLASK_ENV=development flask run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger
```

I got the instructions from [Apache Superset GitHub Contributing page](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#documentation)

Now, regarding the division of the country maps. What I did was download a new `geojson` format map and replace the superset map with the new map. Paste the new map in this directory.

```
cd incubator-superset/superset/assets/src/visualizations/CountryMap/countries
```

If this a new country and does not already exist in the directory, you also need to add the name at controls.jsx file. File is located here:

```
cd incubator-superset/superset/assets/src/explore
```

Open the file and add the new country at the `select_country: {...}` component. I got the instruction at [Superset Visualization Tools Doc](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/visualization.html#need-to-add-a-new-country)

In order for the new country map to show up in the web browser, you need to rerun the command `npm run dev` at assets directory, and restart the server.

That's what worked for me. Hope it'll be helpful for future users.

PS: Don't forget to upgrade npm in case you have an old version. You'll need it for `npm ci` command