# How to run apache-superset in production?

Tags: deployment, web-deployment, apache-superset

I have built apache-superset from [source](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#setup-local-environment-for-development) on my local pc. I git pushed it to my server and now I'm trying to use it in production and access the webapp like: ip:port

I built it the same way as in my local environment, but I cannot access it on the browser using the url ip:port. [This is the way I ran it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330796/how-to-divide-the-country-map-into-more-than-just-the-country-regions-in-apache/54366782#54366782)

I used port 8088 on localhost, and I was using the same on the server.

Comment: Can you give us the command that you are using to run the superset server at least or something that makes your question more understandable.

Comment: @HueyMataruse I managed to fix my problem using [this solution](https://github.com/p10rahulm/superset). I run superset this way: `flask run -p 8088`

Answer (score 1):

Try to access the web app by entering your `<public IP of your server>:8088`.

Answer (score 0):

For example if your server public ip is - 10.65.88.31

Then you can access the application as http://10.65.88.31:8088.

If you are not able to access from above example, then try to run your docker this way

---

### docker run -p 8089:8088 --name superset f70e3db91324

8089:8088 -> local port 8089 bind with container port 8088.

-p is for port

--name is for container name

f70e3db91324 - this is image id

So you can access now via

```
http://<public ip address>:8089/
http://10.65.88.31:8089/ - Example.
```